# SqlCommand Update in SqlDataReader Read Block

Tags: c#, sqldatareader, sqlcommand

I want to get one row record with SqlCommand. After data reader reading, I want to update LastLoginDate. But it fails. How can I update records in drf.Read() block.

```
SqlCommand kf = db.getCommand("SELECT Name FROM Members WHERE ID=1");
SqlDataReader drf = kf.ExecuteReader();
if (drf.Read())
{
    txtName = drf["Name"].ToString();

    using (SqlCommand kf2 = db.getCommand("UPDATE Members SET LastLogin=getdate() WHERE ID=@id"))
    {
        kf2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1);
        int s = kf2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any exception inner message?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it fails'?  Your debugger is your best friend here...

Comment: Have a look at http://lamahashim.blogspot.com/2010/04/c-read-insert-update-delete-from-sql.html

Comment: i looked back again my question. i solved this issue with connection parameter 'MultipleActiveResults=true' in connectionstring. But it is affecting Performance when i compared false value. @YagizOzturk i have multiple SqlCommand. And they use same connection. DataReader doesn't permit that.